# Having Trouble Dropping NaN in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I am having a heck of a time changing a column in my dataset in pandas from an "object" to an "int64". My DataFrame is named bsblandings.

My bsblandings.info() output looks like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 810 entries, 0 to 809
Data columns (total 9 columns):
Year           810 non-null int64
Coast          810 non-null object
Subregion      810 non-null object
State          810 non-null object
Common Name    810 non-null object
Pounds         810 non-null object
Live Pounds    810 non-null object
Dollars        810 non-null object
% Display      810 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(8)
memory usage: 57.0+ KB
```

I need to work with the "Pounds" column, and I successfully changed all of the non int64 values from "*" to "0". I also tried using numpy and NaN.

I used:

```
bsblandings = bsblandings.replace('*', ' ')
```

This did not change the dtype from "object" to "int64" (although all "*" were in fact replaced by "0".

I then tried to sort the Pounds column using:

```
bsblandings.sort_values("Pounds")
```

What I really need is to sort just the Pounds column from smallest to largest (or largest to smallest). When I tried to do this using .sort_values, it did not sort the column properly. Instead I got an output ordered 103800, 10400, 104400, 10600:

```
90  1951    US Atlantic Coast   North Atlantic  MASSACHUSETTS   BASS, BLACK SEA 103800  103800      100%
223 1964    US Atlantic Coast   North Atlantic  MASSACHUSETTS   BASS, BLACK SEA 10400   10400   1687    100%
380 1977    US Atlantic Coast   North Atlantic  MASSACHUSETTS   BASS, BLACK SEA 104400  104400  67172   100%
269 1965    US Atlantic Coast   North Atlantic  MASSACHUSETTS   BASS, BLACK SEA 10600   10600   1379    100%
```

I'm a noob, and I've searched and searched, but I keep hitting a wall. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you do `bsblandings = bsblandings.sort_values("Pounds")` ?

Comment: After the `bsblandings = bsblandings.replace('*', '0')` try `bsblandings['Pounds'] = bsblandings['Pounds'].astype('int64')`

Comment: bsblandings['Pounds'] = bsblandings['Pounds'].astype('int64') yielded ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '*'

Answer (score 1):

This not an error: the sort is correct.  Your `Pounds` column is string format, so that is the sort applied.  Strings are sorted by collating sequence, not apparent numerical value.  Thus, anything starting with "103" is less than anything starting with "104".

If you want a numerical sort, either convert the column to `int`, or specify a sort key that casts to `int` as it goes.

Comment: That makes sense! How do I convert the "Pounds" column to int?

Answer (score 0):

This took care of it!

bsblandings["Pounds"] = pd.to_numeric(bsblandings["Pounds"])

Thanks!